# ggplot won't display in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to develop my first r shiny dashboard. I am facing problem with displaying ggplot. When I am running ggplot code separately in rmd it is working. But when I am trying to run in r shiny the plot is not getting displayed. I have tried to implement in few different ways but still there is no success. Any help much appreciated.

Image

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3S5f.png
```

Full code below:

```
options(encoding = 'UTF-8')

library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(elo)
library(plotly)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
    headerPanel(title = "Project 1"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("Jahr", "Select Year", c("Year" = "Jahr", "Date" = "Datum", "Datebase" = "Datenbank"))
            ),
    
    mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(type = "tab",
                    tabPanel("Data", DT::dataTableOutput("df1_omit")),
                    tabPanel("Summary", verbatimTextOutput("summ")),
                    tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("Plot"))
        ))
)))

options(encoding = 'UTF-8')

library(shiny)
library(datasets)
library (ggplot2)
library(DT)




shinyServer(function(input, output){
    # Return the formula text for printing as a Patienten Daten
    output$df1_omit <- DT::renderDataTable({
        
        df1_omit
        
    })
    output$summ <- renderPrint({
        summary(df1_omit)
    })
    
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
        Jahr_fr <- df1_omit %>% group_by(Jahr) %>% summarise(Freq=n())
        
        g <- ggplot(Jahr_fr, aes(x = Jahr, y = Freq))
        g <- g + geom_bar(stat = "sum")
        plot(g)
    })
    
})
```

Comment: As @Irfan said in the [deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68166784/3358272), you name the plotOutput `"Plot"` but you're trying to send it to `output$plot` (lower-case `p`). Shiny does not inform you if you define `output$somenamehere` that does not have a corresponding element in the UI, so this is a case of your typo being silently ignored.

Comment: Also `plot(p)` is unnecessary - you just need the last line of the `renderPlot` expression to be the plot, `g`

Comment: Hi I changed to ```output$Plot``` but that still doesn't work

Comment: You have to change the `tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("Plot"))` to `tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("plot"))` because your `output$plot <- renderPlot({ })` output is `plot` not `Plot`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Your output name for `renderPlot` were wrong in `tabsetPanel.`

```r
options(encoding = 'UTF-8')

library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(elo)
library(plotly)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

df1_omit <- iris

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  headerPanel(title = "Project 1"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("Jahr", "Select Year", c("Year" = "Jahr", "Date" = "Datum", "Datebase" = "Datenbank"))
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(type = "tab",
                  tabPanel("Data", DT::dataTableOutput("df1_omit")),
                  tabPanel("Summary", verbatimTextOutput("summ")),
                  tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("plot")) #wrong output name, correct is plot
      ))
  )))





server <- shinyServer(function(input, output){

  output$df1_omit <- DT::renderDataTable({
    
    df1_omit
    
  })
  output$summ <- renderPrint({
    summary(df1_omit)
  })
  
# out put name here is plot not Plot
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    Jahr_fr <- df1_omit %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise(Freq=n())
    
    g <- ggplot(Jahr_fr, aes(x = Species, y = Freq))
    g <- g + geom_bar(stat = "sum")
    g
  })
  
})

shinyApp(ui= ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Hello! You are absolutely correct. Just small typo can make a lot of difference in R,.. Thank you so much!!